# Generate random numbers in certain range with certain spacing

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate an nx1 vector of random numbers on a specified range inclusive of the end points with whole number spacing. e.g.

`[0 120] with spacing 40`

For example if n is 10 one such output could be:

`[0 80 0 120 0 0 40 0 120 40]`

It seems like `randi()` is what I should use but it doesn't seem like it's possible to do everything I want with it. Is there another function that I can use to help me with this?

Comment: `randi( [0,120], n,1)` returns a nx1 vector of random integers, including the end points. What are the other thing you want to do?

Comment: My bad, I edited the spacing above.

Comment: what you mean by spacing?

Comment: `randi( [0,120/s], n, 1) .* s` where `s = 40`

Comment: When you say "*random*", do you also mean with equal probability (a discrete uniform distribution)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the toolbox, use `randsample`

```
v=0:40:120 %possible values
n=10 %number of samples
randsample(v,n,true)
```

Comment: I was going to post just that

Comment: And if you don't have `randsample`, you can use `randi` to generate random indices into the vector of possible values: `v(randi(numel(v), n, 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
randi( [0, floor(upperValue/spacing)], n, 1) * spacing
```

if `n = 10`, `upperValue = 120` and `spacing = 40` then you get:

```
ans =

     0
    80
     0
    80
   120
   120
    80
    80
    40
    40
```

The use of `floor` is needed in case `upperValue/spacing` is not an integer. You could do something similar for the lower bound if it is not 0 by using `ceil(lowerValue/spacing)`.